# How do I let the an object know where in a matrix it is?

Tags: game-maker

**Game Engine:** Gamemaker Studio

**Situation:** I want 6 rows of 6 objects, each housed in a cell of a 6x6 matrix. However, this presents the problem of the matrix knowing what's in the cell, but the object in the cell doesn't know where in the matrix it is.

Reason why this is a problem is because I want to have events in the housed object's events that check adjacency to other objects in the matrix.

**Question:** How do I let the an object know where in a matrix it is?

Do I just need to have 2 variables in the object, which is set to the object's position in the matrix, or is there an easier way to do this? Or a better way, I guess.

Or perhaps the question is, is there a better way than the way I am doing?

**How I'm using it Right Now:**

`//check if the last link in the chain is adjacent to the target link`

```
     //includes diagonals
     if(obj_Handle_Links.Last_Link.Matrix_Location_y = (Matrix_Location_y-1)
     || obj_Handle_Links.Last_Link.Matrix_Location_y = (Matrix_Location_y+1)
     || obj_Handle_Links.Last_Link.Matrix_Location_x = (Matrix_Location_x-1)
     || obj_Handle_Links.Last_Link.Matrix_Location_x = (Matrix_Location_x+1))
    {    
        obj_Handle_Links.Match_Length +=1; //because we're increasing the length
        image_index = 1; //this should highlight
        //add to link - implement later
        obj_Handle_Links.Last_Link = id; //makes it so this is what's seen as last link
    }
```

Comment: You should actually try implementing your method before posting questions on here about whether we agree it's the best way. If you end up finding out that it's a poor implementation then that's when you should post on here about it...

I see no problem with implementing it using variables.

Comment: I am implementing it right now. I was just hoping I could get insight in to whether there's a better method than this. I added an example of how I am currently implementing it.

Comment: How are you adding the values? I mean, `Matrix_Location_x` and y

Comment: Because, unless those values are set trough a function, it seems they are hardcoded, making the whole process by hand, and then it could have some optimizations.

Comment: The `Matrix_Location_[x/y]` are just regular number values, and is initialized to 0, then assigned appropriately, when put in to a matrix.For instance, when Matrix[1,2] rolls up the object, it assigns 1 to Matrix_Location_x .

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what it is you mean by "hardcoded"? By the definitions I normally hear (ie. something like "Page_height = 5", rather than something flexible, or reading from somewhere), it would be pretty hard to tell from this bit if it is or not. [I'm not 'dissing' I'm just trying to make sure I get the terminology correct.] Please do elaborate on optimization though. I always enjoy optimization help. (In fact it was the reason I asked.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original**

Your original solution is perfectly fine, you can simply tell your game objects where in the matrix they are using variables...

**However...**

If there is a method being called that your game objects update from you could also pass their position in the matrix through to this method using parameters.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you mean in your "however" section? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm not too sure about specific implementations in your game engine, but say if you have an `update()` method on your game object, you can pass in the objects location as parameters.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense.  I couldn't figure out how to do it outside of just having the left click event (on the objects to be linked). My other idea was to somehow find the x/y position in the room of the objects, and work it out from there, but that ended up looking clunky, with far too much math.